# Is there any way to generate google analytics for the android applications created through phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to generate google analytics for the android applications created through phonegap ? If yes, please guide through steps. if possible, please, provide a video tutorial.

Comment: do some search if you cant find your ans then post here...

Answer (score 1):

Just use this plugin:

https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

It works like a charm. If you need more info, look into the readme